# Simple hello world example MASM x 32 assembly results in error link 2001

Tags: assembly, masm

i want to learn assembly i start learning the 32 intel assembly since i was advised to start in the 32 architecture if i am new to assembly i follow the instructions in the book "Guide to assembly"
by "James T. Streib"  i use "Visual MASM" as my IDE this is the code below

```
; *************************************************************************
; 32-bit Windows Console Hello World Application - MASM32 Example
; EXE File size: 2,560 Bytes
; Created by Visual MASM (http://www.visualmasm.com)
; *************************************************************************

.386                    ; Enable 80386+ instruction set
.model flat, stdcall    ; Flat, 32-bit memory model (not used in 64-bit)
option casemap: none    ; Case insensitive syntax

; *************************************************************************
; MASM32 proto types for Win32 functions and structures
; *************************************************************************  
include e:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include e:\masm32\include\masm32.inc

; *************************************************************************
; MASM32 object libraries
; *************************************************************************  
includelib e:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib e:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib

; *************************************************************************
; Our data section. Here we declare our strings for our message
; *************************************************************************
.stack 100h
     prinf proto arg1:ptr byte
.data

    msg1  byte "hello world",0Ah,0

; *************************************************************************
; Our executable assembly code starts here in the .code section
; *************************************************************************
.code

start:

    invoke prinf, addr msg1

    ; When the console has been closed, exit the app with exit code 0
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

the error is :

```
Assembly1.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _prinf@4
D:\visualmasm\Visual MASM\Projects\Win32Con\Debug\Win32Con.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

i also tried too write the code in "VS code" and run it through the console and it gave me the same results. :/

please could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code ? , also any advice about learning assembly would be really appreciated.
thanks is advance.

Comment: `printf` is a C standard library function, so you'd need to figure out the proper import library for it. Or you could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle perhaps.

Comment: while `printf` is a library function `prinf` is not -- maybe you have a typo in your assembly code?

Comment: actually i changed it from printf to prinf thinking that printf might be causing the problem :/

Comment: i downloaded the assembler from here https://www.masm32.com/ could that be the problem , i couldnt find a way to download it from microsoft official website directly ,since it requires visual c++ 2005 , couldnt  find anyway to downloaded that,, thanks 
 a lot for replying .

Answer (score 0):

There is a `printf` *macro* in `\masm32\macros\macros.asm`

So to use that you'd need to `include \masm32\macros\macros.asm`, and then you could do something like `printf "hello world\n"`. Note that this macro supports `\n`, but I'm not sure if it supports passing a string address, so you may need to use a string literal as in my example.

Also, since you're not using any `%` placeholders, you could use `printc` instead of `printf`.

---

If you need to be able to pass a string address, you could use the `crt_printf` *function* from `\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc`.

```
include \masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
... other stuff ...
invoke crt_printf, ADDR msg1
```

Comment: thanks a lot for replying , the issue is that i dont want to print something , the issue is that the assembler keeps showing the same error for any function i declare and invoke using the same pattern (proto - invoke) , so i need to know what is wrong with the above code so i can fix this problem, since i what to learn the assembly language and might need to use this way again., however the above code you mentioned is 100% useful for printing

Comment: A `proto` is just a declaration of a function. You haven't provided an actual implementation of that function, so when you try to `invoke` it you're trying to `invoke` something that doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying ,sir isnt the invoke statement is the implementation ,the book i mentioned write the code   the same way i  did above, and cant find  way to add  an implementation to a function that is declared that way , i tried to add  blocks to it like prinf proc .. endp but the assembler considered it a redefinition could you help on how should i add an implementation in such case

Comment: Without seeing the actual code you're assembling and the exact error message, it's hard to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: sir you are absolutely right , i didn't provide an implementation for the function, i though that the ADDR and the invoke keyword are used magically  to output the value  it is very naive for me to think so but i feel it might also be a bit on the book since it treated the exact code above as if it will print something to the console for a long time  without clarifying things about "Invoke" and "proto" as you did,anyway i believe i misunderstood it ,i think it is a good book as a whole, hope i dont face any type of problems where i am my own worst enemy especially with assembly, thanks a lot